# Eclipse does not run tests written for junit 3 and junit 4 using junit vintage engine 5

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am using junit vintage engine 5 because I would like to slowly migrate from my old test written for junit 3 and junit 4 to the junit 5 standard.

The dependency I am using is junit vintage engine 5.8.2, and no other.

When I run `mvn test` **in the console**, it correctly executes all tests in the console.

However, when I attempt to run a single test file from within my Eclipse IDE (latest version), the number of tests executed are 0/0. The run configuation for that file shows that **runner junit 5 is used**. The tests executed are 0/0.

Is there a way I can make the Eclipse IDE detect my tests again? Thank you!

Comment: normally if it fails to execute the tests, it gives an error message.

Comment: When manually choosing in the run configuration _JUnit 3_ as _test runner_ it works, right? The automatically selection of the test runner depends on what's on the _Java Build Path_ which is derived from the `pom.xml`. So please show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including a minimal JUnit test class and a minimal `pom.xml`.